# How to always enable command handler in Egit

Tags: eclipse, git, plugins

In Egit, ..... when right click the project, then click "Show in History", the history View shows the list of all commits, select one commit, right click , the pop up menu shows (Checkout, Create Branch, Create Tag, .....Revision Comment). What I need to do is to add a new item in this pop up menu called "Add To Factory", then when click it, go to "AddToFactoryHandler" to do the implementation.

I want this menu item always there when right click the commit in history View.

```xml
<extension  point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
    <menuContribution locationURI="popup:org.eclipse.egit.ui.historyPageContributions">
        <command defaultHandler="xxxxxxxxxxx.AddToFactoryHandler"
                  commandId="xxxxxxxxxx.AddToFactory"
                  label="AddToFactory"
                  style="push" >
        </command>
    </menuContribution>
</extension>
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.handlers">
    <handler class="xxxxxxxxxxx.AddToFactoryHandler"
             commandId="xxxxxxxxxx.AddToFactory">    
    </handler>
</extension>
```

Then in history view, the first time I select any commit, right click , the popup menu shows
grayed out "Add To Factory". then the second time, right click , it goes away.

I do appreciate any help .. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `org.eclipse.ui.commands` extension point to define your command id.

Also note that the `command` in `menuContribution` does not have a `defaultHandler` parameter.

So something like:

```xml
<extension
    point="org.eclipse.ui.commands">
      <command
            id="xxxxxxxxxx.AddToFactory"
            defaultHandler="xxxxxxxxxxx.AddToFactoryHandler"
            description="description"
            name="name">
      </command>
</extension>

<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
    <menuContribution locationURI="popup:org.eclipse.egit.ui.historyPageContributions">
        <command 
                  commandId="xxxxxxxxxx.AddToFactory"
                  label="AddToFactory"
                  style="push" >
        </command>
    </menuContribution>
</extension>

<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.handlers">
    <handler class="xxxxxxxxxxx.AddToFactoryHandler"
             commandId="xxxxxxxxxx.AddToFactory">    
    </handler>
</extension>
```

Comment: I tried, the same problem, the first time could see the "AddToFactory" grayed out in the menu, then click other commit, it goes away.. So the command is not really enabled. Thanks!